# Play Framework - Change the log file location

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, logback

I use a external logback file uing "Dlogger.file" as follow,

```
.....    -Dconfig.file="C:\temp\application.conf" **-Dlogger.file="c:\temp\logback.xml"** -Dpidfile.path=NULL -Dhttps.port=443 -Dhttp.por ..............
```

and my `logback.xml` file looks lile this,

```
<configuration>    
  <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.Logger$ColoredLevel" />

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
 <file>${application.home}/application.log</file>
 <encoder>enter code here
   <pattern>%date - [%level] - from %logger in %thread %n%message%n%xException%n</pattern>
 </encoder>
</appender>
```

Instead of `${application.home}` (in the `logback.xml` file) I want to replace it with a key defined in the application.conf like

```
application.logpath="c:/temp"
```

or in other words I want to define the log file location(path) in the application.conf.

Comment: Can you also add the error message you are getting

Comment: Hi Mok, There is no error message as such. what I want to know is how to to define the log file location(path) in the application.conf.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add underneath `<configuration>`:

```
<property resource="application.conf" />
```

then use `${application.logpath}`:

```
<file>${application.logpath}/application.log</file>
```

Comment: Correct, but it will work only if both files (`application.conf` and `logback.xml`) sit in the same directory.

Comment: Indeed, by default with the templates they're both in that folder.

Answer (score 3):

The most simple way to achieve this would be:

```
...  -Dapplication.home="C:/temp/somedir"
```

But unfortunately it appends one more parameter to your startup command.

---

The reason why your current solution doesn't work is simply because Logback configures itself during class loading, but it is the moment when your config.file is not loaded yet.

So to make it work you can use one little hack: re-initialize logback after startup:

```
import play.*;

public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
    @Override
    public void onStart(Application app) {
        reloadLoggerContext();

        Logger.info("Application has started");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(Application app) {
        // ...
    }

    private void reloadLoggerContext() throws JoranException {
        // Hack to use system properties inside logback.xml
        LoggerContext ctx = new LoggerContext();
        ctx.reset();
        new ContextInitializer(ctx).autoConfig();
    }
}
```

It will work if Play! Framework will export `application.home` as system property or an environment variable. If it won't happen (I don't know *Play!* well), then you can do it by yourself with something like this:

`System.setProperty("application.home", app.configuration().getString("application.home"));`